# Using a select statement to define a table name

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to create snapshot tables as part of script I run regularly.

At the moment I have to manually enter table names, but I would like to call on a field in the base data table to create the snapshot table name.

For example:

Base Data Table = base_data and contains a field for the month it was created in.

Snapshot table = base_data_month

I have already tried to run this to create an automatically named table...

```
create table base_data_snapshot_||(select month from base_data) as 

select * from base_data
```

But this gets a syntax error. For reference there is only one month included in the base data.

Has anyone had any success with this before?

Answer (score 0):

Although we cant combine a running create statement with a select but can use select. So, I guess below should work

```
     create table 
      base_data_snapshot_||t.month
     as 

      ( select * from base_data) t
```

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work. Would wrapping the t.month work I wonder...?

Comment: You can alter the table as rename if that too doesnt work